# Copy & Paste when range meets criteria

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I was just wondering if anyone would know how I can amend the below code so that it will only copy rows where the value in column D exceeds a Value of 0

```
    Sub ADDTOORDERS()
Dim Sh As Worksheet, C As Worksheet, Last As Long
Set Sh = Sheets("Menu")
Set C = Sheets("LensOrder")
With Sh
Last = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B7:D" & Last).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
    .Range("B7:D" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    C.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Sheets("Menu").Range("C3").Select
   .Range("B7:D" & Last).AutoFilter
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You can loop from the bottom of your range assigning the values row by row that meet your criteria.  You can filter the range then copy and paste the visible cells.

Comment: ideally I was looking to have it worked into this code only because I wanted it to be seamless for the user just to click a button and it to just Copy And Paste the Orders they have put a QTY Next to.

Comment: @ScottCraner: why "from the bottom of the range"? I'm asking just because I'm curious and your expertise is beyond doubt.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of deleting.  It can go either way for copy.  My bad @CMArg

Comment: sorry I am new to VBA but how would I put that into the code ?

Comment: @blood_milk_sky google is your friend.  google each step and try to piece it together.  Then come back with your attempts and tell us what is not working.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner I have gone away and have acquired the above but for some reason it is only copying and pasting the first row of the range that is required even though other rows have qtys greater than "0"

Answer (score 1):

```
dim i as Long

for i = 7 to 68 
    If Sheets("Menu").Range("D" & i).Value > 0 Then
        Sheets("Menu").Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Copy
        Sheets("LensOrder").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End If 
Next i
```